# Find minimum in one column based on value frrom another column after joinng 2 tables

Tags: sql

I've searched but can't find an answer to this one. Any help would be appreciated. I'm running a select statement joining to columns which returns some results but I then want to return the value from one column based on the minimum from another column. Heres what I wrote to get the first set

```
        select smtm.MediatorID,count(MediatorID) AS aCount 
        from SystemMonitor sm
        join SystemMonitorToMediator smtm
        on sm.SystemMonitorID = smtm.SystemMonitorID
        where sm.RecordStatus = 1 and smtm.Priority = 1 group by smtm.MediatorID
```

The result I get from this is:

[image: Result]

Now I want to return the value 3 from the MediatorID based on the minimum value in the aCount column.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like MS SSMS output. Assuming Sql Server.

```
    select top(1) smtm.MediatorID, count(MediatorID) AS aCount 
    from SystemMonitor sm
    join SystemMonitorToMediator smtm
    on sm.SystemMonitorID = smtm.SystemMonitorID
    where sm.RecordStatus = 1 and smtm.Priority = 1 
    group by smtm.MediatorID
    order by count(MediatorID) ASC
```